# How to integrate a backend nest auth session based, with frontend in next.js?

Tags: authentication, session, session-cookies, nest

​
I implemented my backend using authentication with sessions however I cannot connect to my frontend application when I make the request through insominia can have the session id saved in my cokkies however in the front-end NEXT.js when I make the request nothing is saved.
How do I do this?

i already read everything about next auth, but a i can find anything like that.

My auth context in front

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

type AuthContextType = {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  signIn: ({ email, password }: { email: string, password: string }) => Promise<void>;
};

export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextType);

export function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const isAuthenticated = false;

  async function signIn({ email, password }: { email: string, password: string }): Promise<void> {
    // Implementação da função signIn
  
    //fazer request para minha api backend que vai retornar um session cookie
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
     
    console.log(response.json());
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, signIn }}>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

how a  i make the request in front form.

```
function LoginPage() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(''); // Use useState para controlar o email
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(''); // Use useState para controlar a senha
  const { signIn } = useContext(AuthContext)
  
 

  const handleLogin = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      email: email,
      password: password
    };

    try {
      const response = await signIn(data);
      console.log(response);
      Router.push('/dashboard');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    
    
  }
```

this is my backend app.js

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
  const PORT = Number(process.env.SERVER_PORT) || 3000;
  const client = redis.createClient({ url: process.env.REDIS_URL });

  const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);

  app.use(
    session({
      name: 'session',
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: new RedisStore({
        client,
        ttl: 86400,
      }),
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      },
    }),
  );

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  await app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
}
```

### -with insomnia ok, i can make the request and have a session cokkie saved, but in front i cannot.

### -when i make login, in frontend, i have a session id saved in my redis database.

Answer (score 1):

People, i get it.

I only put cors configuration allowing my frontend in the backend, and put include in my authcontext.

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as passport from 'passport';
import * as connectRedis from 'connect-redis';
import * as redis from 'redis';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3001'];

  app.enableCors({
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
      if (!origin || allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
      }
    },
    credentials: true,
  });

  const PORT = Number(process.env.SERVER_PORT) || 3000;
  const client = redis.createClient({ url: process.env.REDIS_URL });

  const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);

  app.use(
    session({
      name: 'session',
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: new RedisStore({
        client,
        ttl: 86400,
      }),
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      },
    }),
```

```js
export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextType);

export function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const isAuthenticated = false;

  async function signIn(signInDto: signInDto) {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      // credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify(signInDto),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    if (response.ok) {
      return data.message;
    }
    throw new Error(data.message);
  }
```